# D3 collapse tree at specific level (wrong animation)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, nodes

I'm trying to create a button that collapse all nodes to some specific level. The code is working, but the animation of the node collapsing is wrong (the nodes are moving to the root, not to the parent).

The code: [code pen](https://codepen.io/luiz-eduardo-/pen/povQLEd)
The problem should be here:

```
$("#teste").click(function(){
    root.children.forEach(collapseLevel);
    update(root);
}); 

function collapseLevel(d) {
if (d.depth == 1) { 
console.log(d.name + " " + d.depth); 
if (d.children) {
console.log(d.children);
console.log(d);
d._children = d.children;
d.children = null;
console.log(d);
  }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. You need to update the node:

This part:

```
$("#teste").click(function(){
    root.children.forEach(collapseLevel);
    update(root);
});
```

Remove the update(root), and set the update inside the function:

```
$("#teste").click(function(){
    root.children.forEach(collapseLevel);
});

function collapseLevel(d) {
if (d.depth == 1) { 
console.log(d.name + " " + d.depth); 
if (d.children) {
console.log(d.children);
console.log(d);
d._children = d.children;
d.children = null;
update(d);
  }
};
}
```

You can find the working code here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/luiz-eduardo-/pen/OJParow)